# Kitchen fixture pulled lose from ceiling

Tags: electrical

My kitchen fluorescent fixture has pulled lost from the ceiling and is dangling just by the electrical wires. It is an older home(25years) and the anchor bolts have pulled thru the drywall. I have tried to drill new holes but the drywall just keeps pulling out from the weight of the fixture.
What type of repair person should I call because the drywall may need to be repaired also.
Electrician, handyman, kitchen remodel shop??????

Answer (score 1):

A handy man that knows how to patch drywall and some carpentry should be able to install blocking between the joists that the fixture can be screwed to but if you need someone that can match texture and finish you can get a drywall professional to do that part. You need to have an electrician evaluate the wire to make sure that the wire was not damaged by the fixture hanging by it he would also know how best to re hang the fixture.

Comment: Best method, then the weight of the fixture no longer is pulling on ancient plasterboard. Anything that puts weight on the board puts weight on the nails holding it in place.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use plastic anchors. Instead, use "molly bolts" or expanding steel anchors that grip from BEHIND the drywall.

For Plan B, you could cut a short slot about 2" wide where it'd be hidden by the fixture, and slip a 3"-wide piece of plywood up through the slot. Turn it crosswise to the slot and screw through the drywall into it. Now you can screw your fixture to the plywood with drywall screws.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a month old but I'll add an answer.

A) This is a job for an electrician, NOT a handyman.

B) If this is a fluorescent then it is likely that it is big enough to have at least a few of the mounting screws hit framing above the drywall.